# create header of xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I want to create the header of a xml saved file
**http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">**, but I get error message

```
$uru = "urlset xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd'";

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$xml->formatOutput=true;
$urlset=$xml->createElement("$uru");
$xml->appendChild($urlset);
```

end the error is this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' in /blablabla/blabla/file.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /blablabla/blabla/file.php(11): DOMDocument->createElement('urlset xsi:sche...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /blablabla/blabla/file.php on line 11
```

Thx

Comment: You assigned a variable `($uru)` as a string `("$uru")`, try removing the double quotes.

Comment: nop, this is not the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

`$urlset->setAttribute`

to add attributes.

```
$urlset->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
```

Also you need an element to append it to. 
Here is an example on how your code should look like

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$urlset = $xml->createElement('SetURL');
$urlset->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
$xml->appendChild($urlset);
```

A little sitenote: 
[You should also set your xmlns and xmlns:xsi and not only the xsi:schemaLocation.](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp) 
In your case when working with sitemaps you should set theese attributes then.

```
$urlset->setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
```

This is for the XMLNS ([here is the source](http://www.sitemaps.org/da/protocol.html))

```
$urlset->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
```

And for the XMLNS:XSI([Same source](http://www.sitemaps.org/da/protocol.html))

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMDocument::setAttribute()

Comment: @RobertRouge, I have just updated it as your have forgotten to create your start element that you append into. The example at the bottom should work for you.

Comment: @RobertRouge, No problem :) Btw, you should also add your formatting in the `$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");`, for UTF-8 do it like this `$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");`

Comment: Done. Thank you again

Comment: Actually, you should not set the namespace attributes explicit, but use `DOMDocument::createElementNS()` and `DOMElement::setAttributeNS()`. Done correctly, this will add the namespace definitions as needed. https://eval.in/417913

Comment: @ThW, Interresting, did not know of this method. Could you please elaborate what is better by using your method than the one I suggested?

Comment: This directly creates valid nodes (with the namespace information). Otherwise the DOM will only be valid after reloading, because the properties are not initialized correctly. https://eval.in/418327

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this method instead:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$uru = "urlset xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd'";
$var = $xml->addChild($uru);
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```